# Can't download files from Cloud Storage bucket from React frontend

Tags: reactjs, firebase, google-cloud-storage

I'm trying to download a .pdf file from a bucket in my Cloud Storage but I'm struggling with it. I've set the CORS options correctly and I'm following the tutorial here: https://firebase.google.com/docs/storage/web/download-files#download_data_directly_from_the_sdk.
This is the code which I'm using to download the file:

```
const pathReference = ref(myStorage, `boats/${boatUid}/pdfs/${nameOfFile}`);
const url = await getDownloadURL(pathReference);
const xhr = new XMLHttpRequest();
xhr.responseType = "blob";
xhr.onload = (event) => {
    console.log(`Document downloaded`);
    const blob = xhr.response;
};
xhr.open("GET", url);
xhr.send();
```

I'm not getting any error, instead I'm seeing the message "Document downloaded" in the console but nothing happens after it. What am I doing wrong?

Comment: Where are you using the blob? The code you posted will get the blob from the URL and then do nothing with it, if you want to download the file to your computer there's a couple extra steps.

I can quickly write up an answer if ik what you want to do with the file :)

Comment: Hi @TobyClark, thanks for answering. I just want to be able to download it from my client, nothing fancy

Comment: Have a look at the js library called "file-saver", it is what I have used in my projects to download a blob to the users computer. - a blob is just a way of storing a file so doesn't necessarily mean that it is going to get downloaded,

Comment: I'll try that and if that works I will accept your answer as solution. Thank you!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your code correctly downloads the file and creates a blob object from the response, but it does nothing with the object once it has been created.

Create a URL for the blob object using the `URL.createObjectURL()` method to actually download the file.

You may try this code:

```
const pathReference = ref(myStorage, `boats/${boatUid}/pdfs/${nameOfFile}`);
const url = await getDownloadURL(pathReference);
const xhr = new XMLHttpRequest();
xhr.responseType = "blob";
xhr.onload = (event) => {
    console.log(`Document downloaded`);
    const blob = xhr.response;
    const url = URL.createObjectURL(blob);
    const a = document.createElement("a");
    a.href = url;
    a.download = nameOfFile;
    document.body.appendChild(a);
    a.click();
    document.body.removeChild(a);
};
xhr.open("GET", url);
xhr.send();
```